# Accessing a ClaimsAware Service from an Windows XP client

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-xp, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

We are designing a new N-tier project where clients calling WCF services. In a previous project i worked on, we used implemented own classes for `System.ServiceModel.ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager` and `System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials` (which rely all on the System.IdentityModel somehwere) bound those credentials to the Service Endpoint and used a STS check if the user has the rights to perform the specified operation on the service. All users had at least Windows Vista - so far so good.

Now, we wanted to use a similar approach. But this is then the customer kicks in: they almost all have Windows XP machines, but Windows Identity Model cannot be installed on XP (not supported). So, before we are starting to design in a totally wrong direction, I am better of asking for your advice.

**EDIT**
Ok, i installed a new VM with Windows XP and all the needed assemblies seem to be available, so it might just have been a false alarm then!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly confused about the XP angle. Do you mean you need to develop the application on XP or host it on XP or that XP users will simply use a browser to access a claims-aware application?

If the latter, it's not an issue.

Comment: The later: It is actually a win forms app that needs to authenticate, but since I now have a clean XP installation available, I saw that everything was ready without installing the WIF runtime!